# Nokia 8 touchscreen issues

Tags: touchscreen, 8.0-oreo, nokia-8

It's a brand new Nokia 8, running Android Oreo 8.

When the phone is lying down on the table, the touchscreen becomes somewhat unresponsive. The effect is increased when it's plugged in for charging.

If I touch the screen, the touch does not register on the correct point, or if I draw a line, it breaks off into multiple dots or dashes. On picking the phone up, the issue sort of disappears.

I don't remember the brand name of the tempered glass screen guard I have, but I think it's of good quality, and do not believe it's an issue.

Some [users on *Nokia support*](https://community.phones.nokia.com/support/discussions/topics/7000012056) have said they don't have any screen guards installed, and yet they have the touchscreen issue. I see that many [users on XDA](https://forum.xda-developers.com/nokia-8/help/wierd-issue-nokia-8-t3700007) have the same issue as well.

I contacted *Nokia support* via the built-in app, and their response is that I should bring it to a service center for a close examination. I will do so later.

I'm keeping this question here for posterity. Maybe somebody will know what's going on.

Answer (score 1):

Blame [electrostatic charge](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Electrostatics#Charge_neutralization) for the fault.

The touchscreen in modern phones and tablets is [capacitive](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Touchscreen#Capacitive). When you put your finger on it, your finger and part of the screen forms a capcitor, which allows the touchscreen to determine its position and size by examining its physical indications.

When there is unwanted electrostatic charge, either from another charge source like a metal furniture, or from a badly grounded charger, it can mess up the detection of capacitor of the screen, making it into thinking you're tapping every where. This is the cause for the strange behavior you see.

The solution is to keep your phone away from electrostatic charge, or release it if you happen to see the misbehavior. Releasing charge can be as simple as touching something metal and well-grounded, or touch your phone while *you* are well-grounded.

Comment: I see. I have been using dozens of smartphones over these years, and _now_ this is an issue. I blame Nokia for not knowing how to overcome this issue in the first place. :)

Comment: How does me picking the phone up from the table solve this then? Ideas, any?

Comment: @NVZ The table is a big "charge pool". If your phone stays on it, your body isn't competent at releasing all the charge, But when you pick it up your body only needs to release the small part of the charge on the phone instead of the whole table.

Comment: But isn't that applicable to _all_ such phones? Why is it affecting my new phone?

Comment: @NVZ You know, electricity doesn't go through insulators. Some phones either have a plastic shell that prevents the charge, or have their circuit insulated from the metal shell.